# Solidity OpenZeppelin Documentation: Import other Contract not working

Tags: solidity, javascript, openzeppelin

I just completed the whole documentation for OpenZeppelin and everything was working fine except the import command.

I created a folder in the folder Contracts and placed Auth.sol in there.

Paths:
[myContract\contracts\Box.sol]
[myContract\contracts\access-control\Auth.sol]

In Box.sol i placed following line right before opening contract Box{}

```
import "./access-control/Auth.sol";
```

Then i want to compile with

```
npx oz compile
```

and get the following error:

```
× Compiling contracts with solc 0.7.0 (commit.9e61f22b)
Compilation errors:
contracts\Box.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "access-control/Auth.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "./access-control/Auth.sol";
^-------------------------^
```

When i try

```
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol";
```

I get:

```
Could not find openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol imported from C:\Users\R...\Desktop\dev\myContract\contracts\Box.sol
× Compiling contracts with solc 0.7.0 (commit.9e61f92b)
Compilation errors:
contracts\Box.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol";
^-------------------------------------------------------^
```

I tried several things like changin to an absoluth path or do it without dot (.) but nothing worked for me. Could anyone help me here?

[Link to OZ topic](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/following-the-docs-import-not-working/3450)

Comment: Try `import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol";`.

Comment: Could not find openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol imported from C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\dev\myContract\access-control\Box.sol
× Compiling contracts with solc 0.7.0 (commit.9e61f92b)
Compilation errors:
contracts\Box.sol:4:1: ParserError: Source "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol" not found: File import callback not supported
import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/access-control/Auth.sol";
^-------------------------------------------------------^